# How can I see every change a pip install makes?

Tags: machine-learning, pip, ctypes, xgboost, python-packaging

I'm working on an air-gapped PC and I'd like to install [xgboost](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/1.3.3/) so I can use it in a machine learning model. However, to do so I have to move xgboost over on a thumbdrive.

I've tried downloading it to a similar machine and transferring it over, but it seems like the python `_ctypes` don't get moved over, and I get the following error when I try and use XGBoost:

```
CDLL.__getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal)
    400 def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
--> 401     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    402     if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
    403         func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal

AttributeError: function 'XGBGetLastError' not found
```

I don't understand Python's C based backend, so I'm not sure how to fix this without knowing exactly what changes pip made when installing xgboost.

Is there a way to see all the changes pip makes when installing a package?

Comment: Build a wheel on a similar non-air-gapped machine and transfer that wheel (along all other wheels). Typically `python -m pip wheel xgboost` could be good enough.

Comment: Thank you, what's a wheel?

Comment: Why do  you mean by "*move over*"? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install. Check ***-v*** and ***-t*** arguments.

Comment: A [wheel](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Wheel) (file name suffix `.whl`) is a "built" distribution format for Python libraries, it is the companion to the "source distribution" (sdist). -- If you have wheels, then installing is as easy as unpacking a zip archive, whereas installing from a sdist might require a build step. -- I assumed your issue is related to such a build step, but actually re-reading your question now, it is not entirely clear. -- You mention _pip_, but also mention issue happens when trying to run. Which is it? Install time, build time, run time?

Comment: I didn't try and install it, I moved the installed python files from one computer to another. So the issue is happening at run time.

Comment: Copying the installed files is not what I would recommend. You should copy the wheels to your air-gapped machine and pip-install them there. Probably with the adequate options, such as `python -m pip install --no-index path/to/wheelhouse/*.whl`.